# How do I install GDM on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, gdm

How do I install GDM and any other necessary packages for it to run on the Raspbian image?

Comment: Note that Gnome and GDM may require more memory than you have on the Pi.

Comment: What is GDM in this case?  This is the top result for gnome-disk-utility, which I don't think is what you were asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you *just* want to install GDM, and not an actual window manager, just run.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdm
```

This would be strange though as GDM is a display manager. A display manager only provides the equivalent of a login prompt. In order to actually use your desktop you would need to install a window manager, such as GNOME or Xfce.

So, just in case you would like to also install a window manager then you need to do the following.

1. First, you need to make sure you have `tasksel` and `aptitude`. You can
    install these on Debian-derived systems via `apt-get`.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install aptitude tasksel
   ```
2. Now you need to install the GNOME task via `tasksel`.

   ```
   $ sudo tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
   ```

### References

1. [Gnome - Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Gnome/)

Comment: You can use Xfce alongside GDM.

Comment: Are you saying you can't install `gnome-desktop` using `apt-get`? *Really!?!*

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I don't have a Pi so I can't test if you can use `apt-get` or not. So I'm just going with what the Wiki says.

Comment: Actually, I tried both apt-get, and tasksel, and while tasksel worked, it took 3 tries, and gnome3 won't load due to resource restrictions. I guess this wasn't the best idea I've had. Apt-get did not work, although I don't know if it's a limitation of the Gnome3 desktop, or if it is a resource limitation as well.

Comment: Available gdm package is gdm3

Answer (score 8):

The Pi doesn't have very powerful hardware. GDM will have heaps of Gnome dependencies. It might be better to look for a lighter weight login manager.  [SLIM](http://slim.berlios.de/) might be a good choice (I think Raspbian is using it). Otherwise [LightDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM) is what Ubuntu uses.

Comment: I can understand that. My main point is to get a login manager installed before the GUI. LightDM is what is currently installed, but when I set the GUI to boot automatically, I lose the login password.  There does not appear to be a config setting in lightdm.conf to separate the 2. If I comment out the auto login, then I go back to a console boot, although it requires a password. It was suggested that I look at GDM in the comments of my last question.  Not sure whether it will be the right path, though.

Comment: While this is better information, the answer from @BryanDunsmore answers the question I asked, so I will choose that answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, SLIM works very well, and after installation, I have a GUI auto boot, which still requires a user login. I am still interested in how to get LightDM to do that, but so far, haven't been able.